# Apply gaussian blur to get original image

Tags: convolution, image-processing

Suppose I have an image `A`. Is it possible to construct an image `A'` from `A` so I can get the original `A` after applying gaussian blur (or other convolution kernels) on `A'`? If it's possible, how to do it?

Comment: in the frequency domain, you would divide by the Gaussian filter response; then applying the Gaussian blur would get you back to the original image; there are issues with the stability of the procedure, but this is the basic idea.